# C# ComboBox SelectedItem.toString() not returning expected results

Tags: c#, combobox, treeview

I have a form that allows a user to add players to a roster, by entering the player name and selecting, from a combo box, the division to which the player belongs.

When time comes to add the player to my TreeView control, the node that should display the division selected displays this text instead: System.Data.DataRowView

I got the code to implement this through MSDN here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Here's the code in the load function of the form, to fill the combo box:

```
        private void frm_add_players_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Divisions divs = new Divisions();
        Players players = new Players();
        DataTable dtDivisions = divs.GetActiveDivisions(); //divisions combo box
        DataTable dtPlayers = players.GetPlayersByTourID(this.tourID);
        //set the forms datatable
        this.dt_players = dtPlayers;

        //fill the combo box
        this.cmbo_divisions.DataSource = dtDivisions;
        this.cmbo_divisions.DisplayMember = "title";
        this.cmbo_divisions.ValueMember = "ID";
        this.cmbo_divisions.SelectedIndex = -1;
        this.cmbo_divisions.Text = "Select a Division";

        //set treeview imagelist
        this.tview_roster.ImageList = tview_imagelist;
        this.tview_roster.ImageIndex = 1; //division icon

        //fill treeview
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtPlayers.Rows)
        {
            FillPlayerTreeview(dr);
        }

        //expand treeview
        this.tview_roster.ExpandAll();
        this.ActiveControl = this.txt_player_name;
    }
```

Here I call the function to add the player to the TreeView:

```
    private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object selItem = cmbo_divisions.SelectedItem;
        AddPlayerToTreeView(txt_player_name.Text, selItem.ToString());
    }
```

And here is the function that adds the player:

```
        private void AddPlayerToTreeView(string playerName, string division)
    {
        TreeNode[] tns = this.tview_roster.Nodes.Find(division, false); //try to find the division, if exists
        TreeNode tn = new TreeNode();

        if (tns.Length > 0) //division exists - add player
        {
            tn = this.tview_roster.Nodes[tns[0].Index].Nodes.Add(playerName, playerName);
            tn.ImageIndex = 0; //player icon
        }
        else //division doesn't exist - add division, then add player
        {
            tn = this.tview_roster.Nodes.Add(division, division);
            tn.ImageIndex = 1; //division icon
            AddPlayerToTreeView(playerName, division);
        }
    }
```

And the result is this:
[image: cmbobox issue]

I'm not sure why it won't work.. and I'm at a loss. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is your combobox defined? Obviously, it does not display data by calling `.ToString()` on it. You should not do so either.

Comment: I got this solution through MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You should add the Code where you fill the Combobox with data, it would simplify it for us to help you.

Comment: I just updated my post with the code where I fill the combo box... maybe this would help clarify the problem?

Comment: Your code is fine (for an unbound combobox) except that it is not checking for null; it will crash when nothing is selected. The real problem is somewhere else: _System.Data.DataRowView_ clearly indicates that the thing you are adding is in fact a _DataRowView_...!! So maybe you should use `var selItem = cmbo_divisions.SelectedValue;`

Comment: @TaW SelectedValue would return the id of the division here... and this works fine. I tried with a var type... and I still get that blasted result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, well... maybe something like the following.

Access the combo's data source, which is a DataTable, and extract selected row and column value using selected index. Maybe add some error handling, too.

```
private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var data = cmbo_divisions.DataSource as DataTable;
    var row = data.Rows[cmbo_divisions.SelectedIndex];
    var selected = row["title"].ToString();
    AddPlayerToTreeView(txt_player_name.Text, selected);
}
```

Comment: this works! How I wish I would've thought of that :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddPlayerToTreeView(txt_player_name.Text, cmbo_divisions.Items[cmbo_divisions.SelectedIndex].Text);
}
```

EDIT: Updated to a better way

Comment: @wribit Maybe I edited it too fast to remove an error from copy&paste from your code, but just in case now I rewrote it without copying. That should work.

Comment: I'm sorry... again, I get the same result

Comment: oh, what you need is a property from the selected item, and the property is Text. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object selItem = cmbo_divisions.SelectedItem;
    AddPlayerToTreeView(txt_player_name.Text, cmbo_divisions.SelectedItem as string);
}
```

ToString() will get the type name, but in that case the SelectedItem is a string.